# terminal tools and logs for debugging TCP issues

Tags: linux, terminal, troubleshooting, tcp

I have a server which I am testing for functionality (not load, not stress) with tsung. 50 users / second, 100 total users. Judging from tsung (tsung is the testing framework) graphs, there TCP connections (red line) drops to 0 while the commenced user sessions (green line) does not. Server logs show nothing to be gripping onto, so I am speculating some kind of TCP issue. 
Should this be the case ? Where would I look further on the server, any logs / tools to be looking at ? Only SSH available, no GUI.

[image]

```
> root@XMPP:~# cat /etc/lsb-release  
> DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10 
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

Thank you

Comment: lets say your computer from which you are connecting to tested computer has address 192.168.1.10. Use `tcpdump` to trace if any traffic exists while you use `tsung`. You should exclude the traffic you create with your ssh session. For example `tcpdump src not 192.168.1.10 and dst not 192.168.1.10`. This will show you each packet being sent. If you do not want such detailed information use `iftop` which will show you connections, traffic level and link stats. Additionally use `netstat -patn | grep "ESTABLISHED"` to see all active connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can confirm the status of current TCP connections using netstat:

```
sudo netstat -antpo
```

Especially interresting should be the TCP sessions in ESTABLISHED state.